# Reading docker container config information

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables

There are some parameters set in the docker container. I want to read those configuration from my spring boot application. Can I read it using environment variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify it in your `application.properties` file like below:

```
param.name=${PARAM_NAME_IN_CONTAINER}
```

And after that you can inject that in your application as below:

```
@Value("${param.name}"
String myContainerParam;
```

Comment: Is it possible to bypass the properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Example for property `spring.profiles`

**Way 1**: use custom environment variable `ENV_VAR_IN_CONTAINER`

You need to add to `application.properties`:

```
spring.profiles=${ENV_VAR_IN_CONTAINER}
```

**Way 2**: use spring-friendly environment variable `SPRING_PROFILES`

Spring will automatically use this property.

More information: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config